# Exception when creating XmlSerializer inside an Azure Function V2

Tags: c#, azure, xml-serialization, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function V2 where I am trying to serialize an object to XML.

My object is declared in the run.csx file. (See the code below.)

function.json file

```
{"frameworks": 
 {  
  "net461":
  { 
   "dependencies":
   {                  
     "System.Xml.XmlSerializer":"4.3.0"
   }
  }
 },
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

run.csx file

```
#r "System.Xml.XmlSerializer"

using System.Net;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;

public static IActionResult Run(HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
{
    var fileName = "test.dat";
    FunctionResult resultSet = new FunctionResult(fileName);

    string xmlString = "";

    log.Info("typeof:" + typeof(FunctionResult));
    //This next line throws the error.
    var xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FunctionResult));

    var stringWriter = new StringWriter();

    using (var writer =  XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
    {
        xmlserializer.Serialize(writer, resultSet.Rows);
        xmlString = stringWriter.ToString();
    }


}

//My Object has more attributes than this but this is a simplified version.
//I still get exceptions with this simple object.
public class FunctionResult
{
    public FunctionResult(string fileName)
    {                   
        FileName = fileName;
    }

    public string FileName { get; set; }        
}
```

When I make the call to create the XML Serializer off of the type of my FunctionResult object it throws the following error.

> Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerCSharp1.
>   System.Private.CoreLib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation. System.Private.CoreLib: The path is not of a legal form.
>   Parameter name: path.

When I log the result of 'typeof(FunctionResult)' I get the following:

Code that logs the following result:

```
log.Info("typeof:" + typeof(FunctionResult));
```

> 2018-03-07T18:56:49.213 typeof:Submission#0+FunctionResult

Comment: Sounds like [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26224)

Answer (score 0):

Taking Mikhail's response and mentioning it here, I think you're running into a bug with .NET Core: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26224

It looks like this fix will go out with .NET Core 2.1.0, so once we've added that version of .NET Core to Azure Functions, this issue will be resolved.